# Convert an array to list with specific range in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I want to convert one string array to list with specific range. In my case I always want from index 1 to last index. I don't need the index 0 value included in the list. Is there any direct method that I can use to filter and convert to the list as I need ?

```
public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] optArr = {"start", "map1", "map2", "map3"};
        List<String> list = Arrays.stream(optArr).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: ArrayList class have a [subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)) method, which can be used to slice the list.

Comment: Aside: rename your class/variables to follow proper naming conventions and have meaningful names. e.g. `ArrayToListConversionTest` is also a better name

Comment: Basically all answers until now (except for the [answer by TongChen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53940728/3182664) ) are wasting time and space. (Literally - I mean, here on the site, as well as when they are implemented).  Imagine having a List with 10 Million elements, and you just want to omit the first one. Creating a stream and collecting it to a new list is O(n) in time and space. The answer that uses `Arrays.asList(optArr).subList(1,optArr.length)` is an elegant, concise one-liner, with O(1) in time and space.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`Stream.skip()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(optArr).skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: the only challenge with `skip` would be selecting initial elements instead of skipping

Comment: @nullpointer I think we can all safely agree that for the given use case, your answer is the superior one. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use the overloaded method [`Arrays.stream​(T[] array, int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T[],int,int)) as :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(optArr, 1, optArr.length)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> Returns a sequential Stream *with the specified range of the specified
>   array as its source*.

---

Alternatively(non Java-8), using the [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) is an option, but I would prefer chaining it in one-line instead of creating a new object as:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(optArr).subList(1, optArr.length);
```

Comment: `asList` + `subList` has the advantage of not having to allocate a whole new list. The array is used as as backing storage for the list instead of being copied.

Answer (score 4):

One non Java 8 option might be to just create a view on top of your current list which omits the first element:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(optArr).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> viewList = list.subList(1, list.size());
```

This would mean though that the underlying data structure is still the original list, but one extra element in memory does not seem like a big penalty.

Comment: @nullpointer Um...I am suggesting to just run the original stream, and then view it however you want.

Comment: Why create a new list with streams, and not just `Arrays.asList(optArr)`?

Answer (score 3):

One method use `List.sublist(int,int)`

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(optArr).subList(1,optArr.length);
System.out.println(list);
```

Second method use `Stream`

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(optArr)
    .skip(1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: The first one should likely be the solution. O(1) time and space, in contrast to basically all other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(optArr).skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think it must work.

See docs here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data you might consider :

```
List<String> list = Stream.of(optArr).filter(s -> s.startsWith("map")).collect(toList());
```

But if you just want to filter the first index `sublist` is the way to go.
You do not need to use stream wherever you can.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this.

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(optArr));
List actualList = list.subList(1, al.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Arrays.copyOfRange` to copy an array.

> Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array. The initial index of the range (from) must lie between zero and original.length, inclusive.

```
public static <T> T[] copyOfRange(T[] original, int from, int to)
```

And then convert into `List`

```
List<String> result = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(optArr, 1, optArr.length));
```

**IntStream :** one other way by using `IntStream`

```
List<String> result = IntStream.range(1, optArr.length).mapToObj(i->optArr[i]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use streams? Why isn't some ancient magic like `for-loop`s enough for the task?

```
String[] optArr = {"start", "map1", "map2", "map3"};
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i < optArr.length; i++) // skip first element
    list.add(optArr[i]);
```

The **simplest** tool for the job.